# Proper Way for Create Dynamic UIButton in ScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to `iOS` Development.

I have a navigation based Application, In my application I created dynamic buttons by using a `for loop`.
I have two `UITextField`s (**row** and **column**) in `FirstViewController`.  When user enters a value of **row** and **column** then click on `OK Button` the values of **row** and **column** passes to `anOtherViewController`. In `anOtherViewController` I have to put a logic to create  All Buttons  based on row and column value.

**MyLogical Code:**

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1 ; j <= columns ; j++)
    {
        NSString *btnTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",buttonCount];
        self.btnCount = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        self.btnCount.tag = [btnTitle intValue];
        [self.btnCount setTitle: btnTitle forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnCount addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCountPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.btnCount.frame = CGRectMake(162+changedX, 60+changedY, 43, 43);
        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.btnCount];

        [self.listOfbtnCount addObject:btnTitle];

        changedY = changedY + 50;
        buttonCount = buttonCount + 1;
    }
    changedX = changedX + 55;
    if (i == rows)
        widthScView = changedX;

    if (heightScView == 0)
        heightScView = changedY;

    changedY = 5;
}
```

**My ScreenShot:**

[image]

It works fine, but my problem is that if I enter values of **row** and **column** more then **40** (*about*) then my app takes more time to create the dynamic button. The issue is only related to the time required to create the button.

Is there any way to create a button faster? and I also need to know is if my code is bad for memory management? please help me on this issues.

**For Information :** *I Have no errors generated, I have issue of only time consuming process of creation of Buttons.*

Thank in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You should use `UICollectionView` for this.**

[`UICollectionView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) works a lot like `UITableView` in that it'll manage the cells that are displayed on screen, including scrolling, and it'll ask its data source for new cells as it needs them. You can also recycle cells, so you'll only need to create about enough to display, plus a few extra. This should really improve performance, especially when scrolling.

Apple has some [sample code using UICollectionView here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012860), and watching *Introducing Collection Views* in the [2012 WWDC Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) will get you off to a good start.

> my problem is that If i enter values of row and column more then 40

Forty rows of forty columns would give you 1600 buttons, most of which don't need to exist most of the time. By managing which cells are needed on screen for you, `UICollectionView` will reduce that to around eighty (judging by your screen shot). You should see much, much better performance this way.

`UICollectionView` will also simplify positioning the buttons once you've configured the collection view (which you can do in code or in Interface Builder), you won't need any code of your own for calculating the positions of the buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your replay...but any more information about  UICollectionView ? or tutorial ?? and how can i manage row and column value ?? thanks :)

Comment: you answer is rich but aslo have you another option ?? and i want to alos know that is for loop is bed for me (in my case ¿)

Comment: What if the app requires <iOS6 compatibility?

Comment: @MicRO If the app has to run on systems earlier than iOS 6, you'd want to emulate what UICollectionView does. UIScrollView sends messages to its delegate when it changes the visible region, and you could use those to add and remove buttons appropriately. In any case, the answer to improving performance when you have 1600+ subviews in a view is to avoid having 1600+ subviews in a view.

Comment: @RanjuPatel I've added links to the reference page, sample code, and a WWDC video that should help.

Comment: @RanjuPatel Yes, the `for` loop where you create all the buttons is a problem because you're creating far more buttons than the user can see at once, and the process is surely time consuming. If you incorporate UICollectionView into your project, you won't need the `for` loop at all -- the collection view will ask its delegate (usually your view controller) to create each cell (i.e. each button) as it's needed.

Comment: [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) works on iOS5 and is storyboard compatible. There is no reason not to use UICollectionView

Answer (score 0):

just implement you logic here with your requirement..

```
    int imageIndex = 0;

    int yOffset = 4;//set offset which you want...

    while (imageIndex < rows)        
    {
        int yPos =  7 + yOffset * 30; // set distance in height between two raws

        for(int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
        {
            CGRect  rect = CGRectMake((0 + i * 80), yPos, 80, 31);**// here set frame of every button with different x and y postion// here width of button is 80 and height is 31**

            if (imageIndex < rows) {


                UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                button.frame = rect;
                button.tag = imageIndex;
                [button addTarget:self 
                           action:@selector(btnTemp_Clicked:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

                [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",imageIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];

//                [button.titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
                [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle03.jpg"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal ];                
                [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted ];

                [button setNeedsDisplay];

                [yourScrollView addSubview:button];

            }
            ++imageIndex;
        }
        ++yOffset;
    }
```

See the screen which i got output..

[image]

Comment: what is the problem dude..?? :)

Comment: it row is 150 and column is 200 then i got same problem that i had in my code:

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
    -(void)ScrollViewSetting {

        scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
        scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

        TotalStyleX=25;
        TotalStyleY=18;

        int count=0;
        int px=0;
        int py=0;


        for (int i=1; i<=TotalStyleX; i++) {
            px=0;
            for (int j=1; j<=TotalStyleY; j++) {
                count++;

                UIButton *btn1=[[UIButton alloc] init];

                btn1.tag = count;
                btn1.frame=CGRectMake(px+10, py+10, 300, 380); //you can set your height and width your x and y position
                [scrollview addSubview:btn1];

                px=px+320;     
            }
            py=py+400;

        }
        [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(px, py)];

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replay...Please explain what is new in your code and how can it solve/help to my problem ??

Comment: Where do your `TotalStyleX` and `TotalStyleY` numbers come from? Shouldn't that be `rows` and `columns` per the OP's question? Even so, you're still creating hundreds of buttons when most of those won't be visible at the same time, which means that there's a lot of unnecessary view management going on.